# how to fix React-Redux Provider and connect not available in jest

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I wanna test a currently working react component with redux&hocks

using the default's react-cli test framework jest I made this test file

```js
import React from "react";
import { render as rtlRender, fireEvent, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import RRdx, { Provider } from "react-redux";
import MyComponent from "./";

/* some code */

console.log("the source of my paint", RRdx, Provider);

function render(ui, storeData) {
  const store = getStore(storeData);
  const Wrapper = function ({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>; // this pops an error
  };
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper });
}

/* the rest of the test */
```

The console printsout:

```
 console.log src/components/MyComponent/MyComponent.test.js:55
    the source of my paint { useDispatch: [Function: useDispatch] } undefined

  console.error node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:315
    Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    
    Check your code at MyComponent.test.js:53.
        in Wrapper
```

SO, ¿What I'm missing in the test setup to see Provider? (and also connect, but I found a nice workaround with it)

I'm following the react and redux official guidelines for testing (without enzime).

Comment: Provide the minimal, reproducible test code and component code.

Answer (score 4):

You can add this to your jest config, it'll mock the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks, but will keep the rest of `react-redux` intact, including `Provider`.

```
jest.mock('react-redux', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
    useSelector: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({})),
    useDispatch: () => jest.fn(),
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end some other test script was mocking those attributes from react-redux, so from a side effect behaviour I was getting those errors.